# Python - How do I Remove String from List if Substring is a match (regex)?

Tags: python, regex, list, selenium, substring

Apologies if this has been asked before but im wrecking my head over it and I've googled for hours on this one trying to see if there is a similar solution.

I've a list of url's in which the last 6 characters within '/' '/' are digits eg: [www.test.com/nothere/432432/](http://www.test.com/nothere/432432/)

I'm trying to write the code so that if there is a match to the substring in the position its in in the string it doesnt get added to the list.  The url's im "looking at" are all of the same format hence the use of the regex in the example.

I've tried various if re.match if re.search etc etc and nothing i can put together seems to work.

This is my latest attempt:

```
list = ['www.test.com/nothere/432432/', 'www.test.com/nothere/685985/', 'www.test.com/nothere/655985/', 'www.test.com/nothere/112113/']

regex = re.compile(r'(/\d{6}/)')
filtered = [i for i in list if not regex.match(i)]
print(filtered)
```

My understanding for this is that if the regex.match(i) is not triggered then the item gets added.  Otherwise dont.  But that is clearly not the case and it adds them all irregardless :/

Any and all help is appriciated.

Thanks!

***EDIT***

Another version ive tried which does nothing:

```
            regex = re.match(r'(/\d{6}/)', Adlink) in allAdLinks
            if regex:
                allAdLinks.remove(Adlink)
                print(allAdLinks)
            else:
                print("try again")
                continue
```

Comment: Do you mean that you just don't want duplicates in your list? If that's the case, then just use a set instead of a list.

Comment: thats exactly what i mean :| -  how would i go about changing the list to a set?

Comment: re.match will match from the beginning of the string: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match. You want to use re.search. The python documentation is your friend when you're wrecking your head over issues.

Comment: @kenntnisse - converted to a set would work if the example above was completely accurate however just noticed something after converting - the links in question sometimes are as such: 'https://test.com/1604350/169408/'
'https://test.com/1602436/169408/' so these throw up as different but they both link to the same page - need something will will check the last 6 digits and if they match - ignore adding to list/set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you want to remove all entries from your list where the final 6 digits have already been seen in another url in the list. You can do that by processing the list, keeping the page only if its last 6 digits are not in the set of previously seen numbers (and adding them to the set in that case):

```
urls = [
 'www.test.com/nothere/432432/',
 'www.test.com/nothere/685985/',
 'test.com/1604350/169408',
 'www.test.com/nothere/655985/',
 'www.test.com/nothere/112113/',
 'test.com/1602436/169408',
 'www.test.com/another/685985/'
]
pages = set()
result = []
for url in urls:
    num = re.search(r'\d{6}/?$', url)
    if num is not None and num.group() not in pages:
         result.append(url)
         pages.add(num.group())

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[
 'www.test.com/nothere/432432/',
 'www.test.com/nothere/685985/',
 'test.com/1604350/169408',
 'www.test.com/nothere/655985/',
 'www.test.com/nothere/112113/'
]
```

Comment: Nail on the head ser.  Much thanks!